# Using old laptop as monitor and keyboard

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, multiple-monitors, mouse

This may be similar to other questions, but I can't seem to find anything about my exact question. Please let me know if you find a duplicate!

My laptop is now over 5 years old, and I'm looking to get it replaced. I was thinking about getting a desktop, but one of the things I like most about my laptop is the touchscreen and keyboard (Just the way it works physically).

Is it possible to use my old laptop as a monitor and keyboard for my new desktop? I have read a few online articles, but the main theme seems to be about VMs or some expensive software. I want something easy to set up (But also easy to disconnect if I want to use my laptop as a laptop for some reason), and something is reliable 24/7. I also have an external monitor as well (HDMI), so it would need to work with that as well.

Summary:
Is it possible to use the keyboard and touchscreen of my old laptop with my new desktop and external monitor?

Editing to add that I will be using Windows 10 Pro (Maybe Windows 11 Pro), and that I would like Minecraft with ray tracing on not to be laggy.

Comment: There's either remote admin tools like TeamViewer, AnyDesk, Remote Desktop (built into windows Pro), ... They allow you to remotely log into another computer and use it as if you were sitting behind it. The computer you log into doesnt even need a monitor hooked up to it. Secondly there are "software KVM" tools like Synergy, Mouse without borders, ... They allow you to use your desktop using your laptops keyboard and touchpad, but that will still require the other computer to have a monitor hooked up to it.

Comment: So, the short answer is no.

Comment: Remote Desktop (and it's Win Home equivalent - Remote Assistance - difference is which computer initialises the connection) will be slower video. Don't expect high frame rates in games.

Comment: @user1292580 Frame rate isn't the biggest problem for games over RDP. Many (mostly full-screen) games bypass normal Windows handling and can't have their display reliably send across RDP. For other games it works fine. I regularly play DiabloII and DiabloII-Resurrected on my PC located on the other side of the house using Remote Desktop on my iMac. These particular games work very well (and don't have a MacOS version). I rarely sit behind that PC anyway because if has an old 1024x768 monitor and the chair isn't comfortable. I just RDP into it when I want to use it.

Comment: Will using MiraCast and the extend function work? I do have a monitor that will be hooked up to the new desktop. https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/tech-takes/how-do-i-use-laptop-as-monitor